# Capitalization of the initialism "PC"

Tags: capitalization, initialisms

When using it as 'personal computer', should it be lowercase as opposed to other uses such as 'political correctness' which may be more descriptive through use of uppercase?

Comment: Might be worth noting that when I read your question, with 'pc' in lower case, I assumed you were talking about the [pica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pica_(typography)) - a unit of length. Although, of course, it's very difficult to imagine a situation where the context wouldn't make it immediately obvious what you were talking about. (Also, of course, 'pc' is an *abbreviation* for pica, not an acronym, I merely saw 'pc' and my brain instantly associated it with pica, whereas my brain associates 'PC' with computers)

Comment: A few years ago *Saturday Night Live* (an American TV comedy show) did a skit about a detective (not an employee of the police force) who was culturally and racially insensitive. He was the PI PI — the Politically Incorrect Private Investigator.     :-)    ⁠

Answer (score 3):

The Oxford Manual of Style lists it as *PC* (all caps and no periods) in its dictionary, and this is what I have always used.

> **PC** Panama Canal; Parish Council, -or [sic]; personal computer, Police Constable, politically correct, Privy Council, Privy Counsellor

Comment: I have seen lower-case "pc" used for "political correctness".  (I'm not going to argue whether this is politically correct or not.)   For all other uses (particularly "personal computer") the upper case "PC" would be standard, in keeping with normal acronym usage.

Comment: So have I. The OMS tend to go their own way. I do not have the CMS.